# iPhone App "Content Aggregator" -- concerns about app store rejection

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I just read Apple's iOS application developer guidelines and have a question concerning whether my app is a content aggregator.

The iPhone app is tab-based and displays a table view in each tab.  On clicking a table item, a web view is opened containing a local PDF file.

All of the PDFs are "qualifying times" sheets for national-level swimming competitions.  They are available free online (if you can track them down...), so the app will probably be free to download.

The main purpose of this app is to make it easier for swimmer-athletes to check their own times against all the national competitions.  Is there a risk that Apple could deny this app, since I did technically "aggregate" content?  Or is it too innocent/trivial (I'm not stealing, after all) to be turned away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John,

No one can say for sure, but I'd say the chances of your app being rejected are very, very low.  Key points are to either (a) link to the PDFs, or (b) indicate somehow that you are permitted to use them.  Copyright would probably be the biggest issue.

I think when Apple is saying "aggregator", it really means an app that just reads various RSS feeds and pretends to be an app without any other functionality.  Yours appears to be a reference tool, as I'd have to go get all those links together myself if I didn't have your app.

Comment: Thank you for the key points.  I'll be sure to provide Apple all of the links.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to anyone looking for answer for this

i built content aggregator backend (read from multiple RSS sources) with support for push notification.

Then i develop a flutter app which will show this data as a list/details screens and user can turn on push notification to receive latest feeds alerts.

also I use the  youtube data api v3 to extract popular video lists and data from other channels. i displayed only the title/description thumbnail & upload date.when user tap on the list item to  steam the video i launch the youtube app. (no streaming inside the app)

**publish this app on play store , aug/2020 got reject by apple saying "Guideline 4.2.2 - Design - Minimum Functionality & 5.2.3 Intellectual Property**

> 4.2.2 Other than catalogs, apps shouldn’t primarily be marketing materials, advertisements, web clippings, content aggregators, or a
> collection of links.
>
> 5.2.3 Audio/Video Downloading: Apps should not facilitate illegal file sharing or include the ability to save, convert, or download media
> from third-party sources (e.g. Apple Music, YouTube, SoundCloud,
> Vimeo, etc.) without explicit authorization from those sources.
> Streaming of audio/video content may also violate Terms of Use, so be
> sure to check before your app accesses those services. Documentation
> must be provided upon request.